# I can't show content of a list of items on my div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class (ignicoes) that has a list as one attribute, that list cointains other attributes like dispositivo, latitude, longitude etc. I want to get the contents of that list and show them on my div. However when I run the code bellow nothing is showing. When I do console.log(ocorrencia.dispositivo), it returns nothing. What do you think is the error?

Here is was I have so far:

```
 function getData() {

    $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/8020`, function (data) {
        //o div terá que ser limpo para que a informação não seja subreposta
         document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";    
        $('#myDiv').append(data.latitude);

        var lista = data.listaOcorrencias;
        $.each(lista, function (ocorrencia, o) {


            console.log(ocorrencia.dispositivo);


        });

      });
}
```

Here is what the variable data is returning: 
[image]

Here is what is showig when I run the code:

[image]

Comment: can you share full json code?

Comment: Yes, I just added to the post

Comment: if I'm not wrong, as per your response screenshot, I don't see any object in the name `ocorrencia`  comes under `listaOcorrencias` array list, that's why it returns undefined. Also `$('#myDiv').append(data.latitude)` since `data.latitude` is a string you don't want use append (use this only if you are append some html element) instead use .html() or .text()

Comment: ocorrencia is a new variable related to the each. Meaning that each item that is getting from the list is a "ocorrencia". I'm not sure if I explained correctly

Comment: My bad, let me check it  for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function getData() {

    $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/8020`, function (data) {
        //o div terá que ser limpo para que a informação não seja subreposta
         document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";    
        $('#myDiv').append(data.latitude);

        var lista = data.listaOcorrencias;
        $.each(lista, function (ocorrencia, o) {


            console.log(lista[ocorrencia].dispositivo);


        });

      });
}
```

Does this work for you ? I'm not sure if the data you are receiving needs to be parsed before your use it or not :)

Comment: I don't have problems showing the latitude, I have problems showing ocorrencia.dispositivo

Comment: Oh my bad, I saw your mistake now. 'ocorrencia' in the function is the INDEX of the array, not the element itself, so change it the way I edited my code ==> console.log(lista[ocorrencia].dispositivo);

Also, please use the English language when naming variables :)

Comment: It still doesn't work I get an error saying "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: Are you parsing the data ? If yes - undo those changes, and only add the last change I commented ''console.log(lista[ocorrencia].dispositivo);''

Comment: yes, I copied and pasted the example that you gave, to make sure I didn't miss anything

Comment: Sorry, undo the parse change and only add the changes in the console.log line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208267/discussion-between---and-teresa-alves).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 function getData() {

    $.get(`/api/IgnicoesAPI/8020`, function (data) {
        //o div terá que ser limpo para que a informação não seja subreposta
         document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "";    
        $('#myDiv').append(data.latitude);

        var lista = data.listaOcorrencias;
        $.each(lista, function (ocorrencia, o) {
            $.each(ocorrencia, function (ocorrencia_1, o) {
                console.log(ocorrencia_1.dispositivo);
            });

        });

      });
}
```

Comment: Still nothing happens. I don't think its entering the cicle